# Distance between two bodies remains constant during numerical integration process

Tags: python, physics

I am trying to run a numerical integration code for my research project. It is a 3-atom system which undergo only Lennard-Jones force. However `r_x` variable remains 0 during the process. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out why. This is the output of the code:

```
[[ 1.  9. 15.]
 [ 1.  9. 15.]
 [ 1.  9. 15.]
 [ 1.  9. 15.]
 [ 1.  9. 15.]
 [ 1.  9. 15.]
 [ 1.  9. 15.]
 [ 1.  9. 15.]
 [ 1.  9. 15.]
 [ 1.  9. 15.]]
```

When I check all the variables' values, I saw that `r_x` has just one value and it's zero during the process.

```
import numpy as np

np.seterr(invalid = "ignore")

m = 1

x = np.array([1, 9, 15])
y = np.array([16, 22, 26])

def GetLJForce(r, epsilon, sigma):
    return 48 * epsilon * np.power(sigma, 12) / np.power(r, 13) - 24 * epsilon * np.power(sigma, 6) / np.power(r, 7)

def GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions):
    global xAcc
    global yAcc
    xAcc = np.zeros((xPositions.size, xPositions.size), dtype=object)
    yAcc = np.zeros((xPositions.size, xPositions.size), dtype=object)

    for i in range(0, xPositions.shape[0]-1):
        for j in range(i+1, xPositions.shape[0]-1):
            global r_x
            r_x = xPositions[j] - xPositions[i]
            r_y = yPositions[j] - yPositions[i]

            global rmag
            rmag = np.sqrt(r_x*r_x + r_y*r_y)

            if(rmag[0]==0 or rmag[1]==0 or rmag[2]==0):
                rmag += 1
                
                force_scalar = GetLJForce(rmag, 0.84, 2.56)
                
                force_x = force_scalar * r_x / rmag
                force_y = force_scalar * r_y / rmag

                xAcc[i,j] = force_x / m
                xAcc[j,i] = - force_x / m
            
                yAcc[i,j] = force_y / m
                yAcc[j,i] = - force_y / m
            
            else:
                force_scalar = GetLJForce(rmag, 0.84, 2.56)

                force_x = force_scalar * r_x / rmag
                force_y = force_scalar * r_y / rmag

                xAcc[i,j] = force_x / m
                xAcc[j,i] = - force_x / m

                yAcc[i,j] = force_y / m
                yAcc[j,i] = - force_y / m

    return np.sum(xAcc), np.sum(yAcc)

def UpdatexPos(x, v_x, a_x, dt):
    return x + v_x*dt + 0.5*a_x*dt*dt

def UpdateyPos(y, v_y, a_y, dt):
    return y + v_y*dt + 0.5*a_y*dt*dt

def UpdatexVel(v_x, a_x, a1_x, dt):
    return v_x + 0.5*(a_x + a1_x)*dt

def UpdateyVel(v_y, a_y, a1_y, dt):
    return v_y + 0.5*(a_y + a1_y)*dt

def RunMD(dt, number_of_steps, x, y):
    global xPositions
    global yPositions
    xPositions = np.zeros((number_of_steps, 3))
    yPositions = np.zeros((number_of_steps, 3))

    v_x = 0
    v_y = 0

    a_x = GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions)[0]
    a_y = GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions)[1]

    for i in range(number_of_steps):
        x = UpdatexPos(x, v_x, a_x, dt)
        y = UpdateyPos(y, v_y, a_y, dt)

        a1_x = GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions)[0]
        a1_y = GetAcc(xPositions, yPositions)[1]

        v_x = UpdatexVel(v_x, a_x, a1_x, dt)
        v_y = UpdateyVel(v_y, a_y, a1_y, dt)

        a_x = np.array(a1_x)
        a_y = np.array(a1_y)

        xPositions[i, :] = x
        yPositions[i, :] = y

    return xPositions, yPositions

sim_xpos = RunMD(0.1, 10, x, y)[0]
sim_ypos = RunMD(0.1, 10, x, y)[1]

print(sim_xpos)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some details with your code, the main reason that it isn't running is because of this line `return np.sum(xAcc), np.sum(yAcc)`, you calculated a matrix of accelerations from the interactions between all the particles where you added the acceleration of one particle and the inverse of that acceleration to the other, since the mass of all particles is the same then the accelerations are the same, then you sum all the elements of the matrix, so all the terms cancel out, and instead of returning the acceleration of each particle you return the sum of the accelerations of ALL the particles, and given that they all have the same mass, is just 0, even if it was not 0 it would have been wrong because you where mixing them all, so all the particles would have the same acceleration and move in the same direction.

Details purely about the code

- 1

In that same function you have also something that can be improved, you have something like

```
if condition:
    A_statement
    B_statement
else:
    B_statement
```

that is the same as

```
if condition:
    A_statement
B_statement
```

since `B_statement` is always going to get executed.

- 2

You don't have to use `global` on the variables you used it, where you use them they are still in scope, basically use it when you are going to use that variable in other functions, basically everything that has the same number of tabulations or more knows about that variable, and that ends in the first line that is less tabulated than that one, that leads to the next point.

- 3

```
def UpdatexVel(v_x, a_x, a1_x, dt):
    return v_x + 0.5*(a_x + a1_x)*dt

def UpdateyVel(v_y, a_y, a1_y, dt):
    return v_y + 0.5*(a_y + a1_y)*dt
```

There is no need to make this two identical functions, the only difference is the name, they make the same thing, the name of the parameters of the function go out of scope when you end the function body, so you could reuse the a single function for both x and y.

Some examples

```py
def fun(a):
   return a
x = a # NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

a is not in scope when we use it for `x`, it only existed in the body of `fun`, so you could reuse that name for other variable or parameter.

```py
a = 1
def fun(a):
  return 2 + a
print( fun(7) ) # = 9
```

That happens because a is shadowed by the function parameter of the same name, while

```py
a = 1
def fun():
  return a
print( fun() ) # = 1
```

because when `fun()` looks for a it doesn't find it in its scope, so it looks at a higher scope, and finds a variable `a` that holds the value `1`

- 4

```py
    return xPositions, yPositions

sim_xpos = RunMD(0.1, 10, x, y)[0]
sim_ypos = RunMD(0.1, 10, x, y)[1]
```

This is smaller, but python has `tuples` so this code that repeats the calculations of `RunMD` (which you don't want), can be simplified to

```py
    return xPositions, yPositions

sim_xpos, sim_ypos = RunMD(0.1, 10, x, y)
```

where the pair that is returned by `RunMD` is assined to the pair (a tuple of two elements for python) `sim_xpos` and `sim_ypos`.

If I where to rewrite parts of that code, I would remove numpy to test the algorithm, and then bring numpy to vectorize the operations and make the code much more efficient, it would look something like this

```py
import math

def cart_to_polar(x, y):
    rho = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    phi = math.atan2(y, x)
    return rho, phi

def polar_to_cart(rho, theta):
    x = rho * math.cos(theta)
    y = rho * math.sin(theta)
    return x, y

def GetLJForce(r, epsilon, sigma):
    return 48 * r * epsilon * ( ( ( sigma / r ) ** 14 ) - 0.5 * ( ( sigma / r ) ** 8 ) ) / ( sigma ** 2 )

def GetAcc(x_positions, y_positions, m):
    xAcc = [0]*len(x_positions)
    yAcc = [0]*len(x_positions)

    for i in range(0, len(x_positions)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(x_positions)):

            # calculations are made from the point of view of i, and then flipped for j
            delta_x = x_positions[j] - x_positions[i]
            delta_y = y_positions[j] - y_positions[i]

            radius, theta = cart_to_polar(delta_x, delta_y)
            # in case two particles are at the same place
            # this is some times called a cutoff radius
            if radius==0: radius = 1e-10

            force_mag = GetLJForce(radius, 0.84, 2.56)

            # since the polar coordinates are centered in the i particle the result is readilly usable
            # particle j interaction with particle i
            force_x, force_y = polar_to_cart(force_mag, theta)
            xAcc[i] += force_x / m[i]
            yAcc[i] += force_y / m[i]

            # flip the sing of the force to represent the 
            # particle i interaction with particle j
            force_x, force_y = polar_to_cart(-force_mag, theta)
            xAcc[j] += force_x / m[j]
            yAcc[j] += force_y / m[j]

    return xAcc, yAcc

def update_pos(x, v, a, dt):
    return x + v*dt + 0.5 * a * dt ** 2

def update_vel(v, a, dt):
    return v + a * dt

def runMD(dt, x, y, v_x, v_y, m):

    num_particles = len(x)

    a_x, a_y = GetAcc(x, y, m)

    for i in range(num_particles):
        v_x[i] = update_vel(v_x[i], a_x[i], dt)
        v_y[i] = update_vel(v_y[i], a_y[i], dt)

    for i in range(num_particles):
        x[i] = update_pos(x[i], v_x[i], a_x[i], dt)
        y[i] = update_pos(y[i], v_y[i], a_y[i], dt)

    return x, y

# number of particles in the system
num_particles = 3
# mass of the particles
m = [1] * num_particles
# starting positions
x = [1, 9, 15]
y = [16, 22, 26]
# starting velocities
v_x = [0] * num_particles
v_y = [0] * num_particles
# number of steps of the simulation
number_of_steps = 10

# the simulation
for i in range(number_of_steps):
    x, y = runMD(0.1, x, y, v_x, v_y, m)
    print(x, y)
```

I don't know if the physics is precisely how it should be for molecular dynamics, when I was in physics I only made simulations of dynamical systems, maybe my approach is too precise or classical for your system, either way you can use it to compare.

Comment: First of all, your answer is so useful. Thank you so much. I want to ask one more thing here. What if I would want add one more interaction to the system such as spring force between atoms except one which will be sliding through other atoms at the chain. Have you any idea?

Comment: Anytime. To do that I would place it at the end of the `GetAcc` function to add the accelerations to the particles that are linked and not having to change other parts of the code, the process should be similar to the one with L-J, just with a different method for calculating the force, and only involving two particles. So in the `GetAcc` function you basically do the summation of the forces of each particle and return their accelerations to update the over variables.

Comment: You might also be interested in this book that Springer made available for free for the Covid-19 quarantine [Basic Concepts in Computational Physics](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-27265-8)